ESP32 WiFi.h is triggering other ISR callback
I have a class function that is setup as an ISR whenever GPIO pin 39 senses a falling signal.  This works as expected and counts high to low transitions from an input sensor.
However, once I connect to the WiFi network using the WiFi.h library the ISR callback is getting trigger about 10X perseond, even when there is not GPIO pin activity.  I have read that once connected to a network the WiFi routine constantly checks for connectivity at a nominal rate of 10 Hz.  So it seems that this WiFi routine is also triggering a call to my class function ISR callback.
Is there a way to stop this from happening?
This is the main.cpp file:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "pump.h"
#include "WiFi MQTT2.h"

#define PUMP_PIN 27
#define FLOW_PIN 39

PumpControl pump( PUMP_PIN, FLOW_PIN );

void setup() {
  // Initialize the USB serial communication
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pump.Init();

  initWiFi( 5 );
}

void loop() {

  Serial.printf( "flowCount: %u\n", pump.flowCount );
  delay(1000);

}

This is the pump.h file:
#pragma once
#include <Arduino.h>

// Note: this is needed in the ESP32 environment
#include <FunctionalInterrupt.h>

class PumpControl {

  public:
    PumpControl( uint8_t _pump_pin, uint8_t _flow_pin ); 
    volatile uint32_t flowCount;
    uint8_t Init();

  private:
    void IRAM_ATTR FlowCounter();
    uint8_t pump_pin; // Output pin to the vibratory pump
    uint8_t flow_pin; // Flow sensor input pin
 
};

The pump.cpp file:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "pump.h"

PumpControl::PumpControl( uint8_t _pump_pin, uint8_t _flow_pin ) {
    pump_pin = _pump_pin;
    flow_pin = _flow_pin;
}

void IRAM_ATTR PumpControl::FlowCounter() {
  // Increment the flow counter
  flowCount++;  
  return;
}

uint8_t PumpControl::Init() {
  
  // Set the water pump SSR control pin as output on the GPIO
  pinMode( pump_pin, OUTPUT );
  
  // As a precaution set the output low
  digitalWrite( pump_pin, LOW );

  // Setup the flow sensor pin as an input (active low and use an internal pullup).
  pinMode( flow_pin, INPUT_PULLUP );
  attachInterrupt( flow_pin, std::bind(&PumpControl::FlowCounter, this), FALLING );

  return true;
  
}

The Wifi MQTT.h file:
#pragma once
#include <Arduino.h>

extern bool wifiActive;

bool initWiFi( uint8_t );
long getRSSI();

And the WiFi MQTT.cpp file:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>  // Library used for ESP32 boards
#include "WiFi MQTT2.h"

// Verify these are the setting for the WiFi network
#define WIFI_SSID "The Bird House" // This is the WiFi network name (aka: SSID)
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "***************" // The SSID password
#define DEVICE_NAME "Stanley Steamer" // Device name that should appear on the WiFi router.

// Intantiate a WiFi Client object
WiFiClient wifiClient;

bool wifiActive;

bool initWiFi( uint8_t maxTries=10  ) {
    
    WiFi.mode( WIFI_STA );  // Set the device as a station (client) on the WiFi network
    WiFi.config( INADDR_NONE, INADDR_NONE, INADDR_NONE, INADDR_NONE );
    // Change the hostname name of WiFi connected device.
    WiFi.hostname( DEVICE_NAME );

    // Connect to the specified WiFi network name
    Serial.print("Connecting to "); Serial.print( WIFI_SSID );
    WiFi.begin( WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD );

    // Wait until the connection has been confirmed before continuing
    while ( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED and maxTries > 0 ) {
        digitalWrite( LED_BUILTIN, !digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN) );
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(2000);
        maxTries--;
    }

    if ( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {
        Serial.println( "\n*** No connection to WiFi." );
        return false;
    }

    wifiActive = true;

    // Debugging - Output the IP Address of the NodeMCU
    Serial.println( "\nWiFi connected" );
    Serial.print( "Connected as IP address: " );
    Serial.println( WiFi.localIP() );

    Serial.printf( "WiFi connection name is: %s\n", WiFi.getHostname() );

    Serial.println("WiFi setup complete.");

    return true;

}

long getRSSI() {
    return WiFi.RSSI();
}

This is the output when connected to the WiFi:
---- Opened the serial port COM14 ----
Connecting to The Bird House.
WiFi connected
Connected as IP address: 192.168.1.100
WiFi connection name is: Stanley Steamer
WiFi setup complete.
flowCount: 17
flowCount: 27
flowCount: 37
flowCount: 47
flowCount: 56

When the initWifi( 5 ); line is comment out I get this output:
---- Opened the serial port COM14 ----
flowCount: 0
flowCount: 0
flowCount: 0
flowCount: 0
flowCount: 0
flowCount: 0
flowCount: 0

I am using an Adafruit HUZZAH32 board and programming it using PlatformIO in Visual Studio Code.
Update:  I just discovered this problem seems to be specific pin related.  When I use pins 36 and 39 I get the unwanted triggers.  But there are no false triggers when using pins 34 and 26.  Pins 34, 36 and 39 are identified as input/ADC only pins.  It seems odd that 34 works while 36 and 39 do not.
Pin 26 is a normal GPIO pin.
This is the new main.cpp file:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "pump.h"
#include "WiFi MQTT2.h"

#define PUMP_PIN 27
// #define FLOW_PIN 4 // 36 does not work: 36, 39

PumpControl pump26( PUMP_PIN, 26 ); // This is a regular GPIO pin
PumpControl pump34( PUMP_PIN, 34 ); // This is labeled as an input/ADC only pin
PumpControl pump36( PUMP_PIN, 36 ); // This is labeled as an input/ADC only pin
PumpControl pump39( PUMP_PIN, 39 ); // This is labeled as an input/ADC only pin

void setup() {
  // Initialize the USB serial communication
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pump26.Init();
  pump34.Init();
  pump36.Init();
  pump39.Init();
  
  initWiFi( 5 );
}

void loop() {

  Serial.printf( "flowCount values Pin 26: %u Pin 34: %u Pin 36: %u Pin 39: %u\n", pump26.flowCount, pump34.flowCount, pump36.flowCount, pump39.flowCount );
  delay(1000);

}

And this is the output:
---- Opened the serial port COM14 ----
Connecting to The Bird House.
WiFi connected
Connected as IP address: 192.168.1.100
WiFi connection name is: Stanley Steamer
WiFi setup complete.
flowCount values Pin 26: 0 Pin 34: 0 Pin 36: 34 Pin 39: 17
flowCount values Pin 26: 0 Pin 34: 0 Pin 36: 54 Pin 39: 27
flowCount values Pin 26: 0 Pin 34: 0 Pin 36: 72 Pin 39: 36
flowCount values Pin 26: 0 Pin 34: 0 Pin 36: 92 Pin 39: 46
flowCount values Pin 26: 0 Pin 34: 0 Pin 36: 112 Pin 39: 56
flowCount values Pin 26: 0 Pin 34: 0 Pin 36: 132 Pin 39: 66
flowCount values Pin 26: 0 Pin 34: 0 Pin 36: 151 Pin 39: 76
flowCount values Pin 26: 0 Pin 34: 0 Pin 36: 169 Pin 39: 85
flowCount values Pin 26: 0 Pin 34: 0 Pin 36: 188 Pin 39: 95
flowCount values Pin 26: 0 Pin 34: 0 Pin 36: 208 Pin 39: 105
flowCount values Pin 26: 0 Pin 34: 0 Pin 36: 227 Pin 39: 115
flowCount values Pin 26: 0 Pin 34: 0 Pin 36: 245 Pin 39: 124

The simple solution is to not use pins 36 or 39 for ISRs, but for my application I need all the "normal" GPIO pins for outputs.  I need to use 34, 36 and 39 for my only 3 input signals.  Unfortunately, all require ISR callbacks.  So a solution the trouble with pins 36 and 39 would be very helpful.

ESP32 datasheet clearly mentioned that pin 34-39 are input pins "with no output buffer and without internal pull-up or pull-down resistor", if you want to use pin as GPIO INPUT with INPUT_PULLUP, use other pins. Pin 36 and 39 basically are the differential input of ADC0, which is why they had the name of SENSOR_VP and SENSOR_VN.
